# CA2202: How to circumvent the warning?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I ran my code through code analysis in visual studio 2015. It shows a warning that I do not know how to circumvent. The below snippet shows the principle. This program produces the warning CA2202:

> "Object 'memoryStream' can be disposed more than once in method...".

```
private void tt()
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
    StreamWriter streamWriter = null;
    memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.Unicode);
    memoryStream.Close();
    streamWriter.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method description of `StreamWriter.Close` according to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.streamwriter.close(v=vs.110).aspx) is "Closes the current StreamWriter object and the underlying stream.". Therefore, `memoryStream.Close()` and `streamWriter.Close()` close the underlying stream. This was diagnosed by the compiler and recommended to avoid. Also make sure that you call `streamWriter.Close()` since this method flushes the buffers in the `streamWriter`.

Also the `using` keyword (scoping including a final call on .Dispose() / .Close()) is highly recommendable for these kind of operations. Please refer to the following [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/wtbhzte9(v=vs.110).aspx) page about a typical usage.